# copy data from one datastore to another using fuseki

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena, fuseki

I want to take data from my existing datastore (triples) and upload to another datastore which I created using Fuseki. I have all my classes, properties, instances in this data which I want to keep safe in another datasotre, in case I mess up my dataset. 
I have tried using

```
select *
where {?x ?c ?v.}
```

then downloading data in xml or csv format and then tried to upload it onto my other datastore. But, this process created a lot of blanknodes.
I would really appreciate if someone could share their experience.

Comment: Try `construct {?s ?p ?o } { ?s ?p ?o }`, which will return rdf contained in the default graph.

Answer (score 1):

The SPARQL graph store protocol can be used to work with graphs. You can PUT or POST graphs directly into the store by using the appropriate service fuseki:serviceReadWriteGraphStore in Fuseki.  Typically, `http://.../dataset/data`.

```
POST http://.../dataset/data?default
```

to send to the default graph.